Is there a way to get Teams to delete a folder without having to delete its contents first?
When I try to delete a non-empty folder from Teams, it says, “You have to delete all the items in this folder before you can delete the folder.” However, most of the folders I'm trying to delete have lots of subfolders in them, making this extremely time-consuming. Is there a way to change this so that I don't have to go into each individual subfolder and manually delete the files?

Where are you doing this in Teams? Is this a Sharepoint folder, or a specific Teams app? Is this a business environment, or a personal Teams/Microsoft account?
